# A positive integer is called ”nice” if it has at least three distinct positive divisors. How many ”nice” integers are there less than 100?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

Well I've tried counting
p^2 <= 100 (where p is a prime) there are 4 such no.s
{4, 9, 25, 49} which have exactly 3 distinct divisors but how'd I be covering all cases less than 100

Thank You

Comment: Your nice numbers are just the composite numbers. Are you sure you got the question right? (You say "at least" in the title but "exactly" in the question body.)

Comment: uhh I actually calculated no which did have exactly 3 unique divisors but was stuck for > 3 and as pointed out by one OP the answer is the number of composites less than 100 which follows from the Fundamental Thrm of Arithmetics. Pretty dumb that I forgot that one but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 74! (Not a factorial, just a regular exclamation mark) Because you just want the amount of composites less than 100, just subtract the number of primes less than 100 and remove 1 so we don't include the number 1 which is neither Prime not Composite.

Comment: Thanks! that was so dumb of me.... 
it follows from the Fundamental Thrm of Arithmetics

Comment: @AYUSHBANERJEE this must be my first good post/answer on mathematics.